# How correctly logout user in React Native App?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I wonder what is the correct way of logging out user. In my code I created in `Navigation` context that provides `logout()` function. But by doing this I am able to reset `AsyncStorage` and do request to server to expire token. How can I navigate to `loginscreen`? Is it a correct implementation? If not how do you do this? Thanks for replies.

```
export const Navigation = () => {
  const contextValue: AuthContextProps | undefined =
    React.useContext(AuthContext);

  if (contextValue == undefined) {
    console.log("Undefinied context value from index.tsx");
  }
  const handleSignOut = () => {
    contextValue?.logout();
  };
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {contextValue?.splashLoading ? (
          <Stack.Screen
            name="MainPage"
            component={MainPageScreen}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
        ) : contextValue?.userInfo.access_token ? (
          <Stack.Group
            screenOptions={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          >
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Navigate"
              options={{ title: "InnerNavigation" }}
            >
              {() => <InnerNavigation handleSignOut={handleSignOut} />}
            </Stack.Screen>
          </Stack.Group>
        ) : (
          <Stack.Group
            screenOptions={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          >
            <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={WelcomeScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="RecoverPassword"
              component={RecoverPasswordScreen}
            />
            <Stack.Screen name="PersonalData" component={PersonalDataScreen} />
          </Stack.Group>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Comment: have you tried the documentation? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating
use RNSecureStorage for auth. note you can import navigation into any component with useNavigation from react Navigation. also note you can only use navigation inside the navigation stack so implement that in your InnerNavigation component

Comment: Hi, I found the solution. Just needed to clear contextValue and then access_token is empty so it redirects me to WelcomeScreen instantly, Still prefer LoginScreen but i'm looking how can I reach it :) Thanks for suggestions. I gonna read about RNSecureStorage.